# Не работает вызываемый по нажатию кнопки метод

Tags: c#, winforms

Почему не работает вызываемый метод Pict_SaveFile?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace addwaternark
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string Picture_FromFile()
        {

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

            {

                return openFileDialog.FileName;
            }
            return "";
        }
  public string Picture_SaveFile()
        {

            if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK);
            saveFileDialog.Filter = "Image Files(*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG|All files (*.*)|*.*"; //фильтруем все картинки по формату
            {
                return saveFileDialog.FileName;
            }
            return "";
        }

        private void openButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap image;
            AutoScroll = true;
            AutoScrollMinSize = pictureBox1.Size;

            {
                open_dialog.Filter = "Image Files(*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG|All files (*.*)|*.*"; //фильтруем все картинки по формату
                if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {

                    fileNameBox.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
                }
            }

            {
                try
                {
                    image = new Bitmap(openFileDialog.FileName);   //Bitmap для открываемой картинки


                    pictureBox1.Size = image.Size;    //Картинка подгоняется под размер picturebox
                    pictureBox1.Image = image;
                    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
                }

                catch
                {
                    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Невозможно открыть выбранный файл",
                    "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);    //Если это НЕ картинка
                }
            }
        }

        private void saveAs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Picture_SaveFile();
        }

        private void addWaterMark_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            using (Image image = Image.FromFile(Picture_FromFile()))
            using (Image watermarkImage = Image.FromFile(Picture_FromFile()))
            using (Graphics imageGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
            using (TextureBrush watermarkBrush = new TextureBrush(watermarkImage))
            {
                int x = (image.Width / 2 - watermarkImage.Width / 2);
                int y = (image.Height / 2 - watermarkImage.Height / 2);
                watermarkBrush.TranslateTransform(x, y);
                imageGraphics.FillRectangle(watermarkBrush, new Rectangle(new Point(x, y), new Size(watermarkImage.Width + 1, watermarkImage.Height)));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Как именно не работает?

Answer (score 0):

Наведите порядок в скобках и точках с запятой:

```
public string Picture_SaveFile()
{
  // фильтруем все картинки по формату
  saveFileDialog.Filter = 
    "Image Files(*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG|All files (*.*)|*.*";
  if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
     return saveFileDialog.FileName;
  }
  return "";
}

private void saveAs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string fileName = Picture_SaveFile();
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
  {
    // ну, и без кода, сохраняющего файл, программе будет трудно
  }
}
```

Comment: В качестве пустого значения строки концептуальнее возвращать `null`.